# SVG text clippath in Firefox

Tags: css, svg, css-transforms, clip-path

I am using a text clippath to create an SVG displaying text so that I can animate the background to come in for a fun text reveal effect.

It works great in Chrome and Safari but in Firefox there are issues with the clippath.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 150">

  <!-- Clippath  with text -->
  <clippath id="cp-text">
   <text text-anchor="left"
      x="0"
      y="50%"
      dy=".35em"
      class="text--line"
      >
   hello
   </text>
  </clippath>


  <!-- Group with clippath for text-->
  <g clip-path="url(#cp-text)" class="colortext">
    <!-- Animated shapes inside text -->
    <polyline class="anim-shape" points="559.91 153.84 526.17 -11.62 478.32 -11.62 512.05 150.84 559.91 153.84" style="fill: #4c4870"/>
    <polyline class="anim-shape" points="599.75 149.75 599.92 -0.62 528.07 -0.62 558.75 150.75 599.75 149.75" style="fill: #93d2c4"/>
    <polygon class="anim-shape" points="479.07 -11.62 395.78 -11.62 429.52 153.84 512.8 153.84 479.07 -11.62" style="fill: #f89c2c"/>
  </g> 
</svg>
```

I'm using CSS transforms to animate the polgyon shapes on load (scale and translate).

See codepen demo here: https://codepen.io/njpatten/pen/zwEeev

I've tried updating the polgyons inside the svg but it seems to be a problem with the clippath text rendering being delayed.

Any idea what might be the problem in Firefox? Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help!

Comment: BTW, its very smart and great idea for such effect :) well done.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in Firefox. I have reported it https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1378707

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Firefox requires something to render beside the text mask you have created, while the animated shapes are with scale of 0,1 , it gets some problems. 
I added this

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="transparent" />
```

just before first polygon and seems it now works similar to Chrome.
I think you can work with `width` and `height` if you don't want full width and height.

Hope it helps

Comment: Well done finding this workaround. Note that this fix only helps for the portion of the group covered by this element. So if the element is wider than 1000, the animation will still partly fail. A better rect would be something like  `<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="transparent" />`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)